# Error with dependency injection and generic base class

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning repository and unit of work patterns using generics and dependency injection.  I have a persistent error that I have been churning on and I am clearly missing something fundamental.

I am getting the following error which whilst I understand that it is looking for a database table column called 'Id'

Because my Entity class inherits from BaseEntity I suspect this is the problem but I don't understand why and what I am best to do to fix it.

```
public class BaseEntity<T>
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**Error returned**

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' >occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command >definition. See the inner exception for details.

**Inner exception**

> {"Invalid column name 'Id'."}

To add some context I am using EF6 MVC5 and AutoFac for the Dependancy injection.

**Entity class**
(A column 'id' doesn't exist in the database - the key in the database is 'EmrgencyAttendanceId') and the Entity class  also sets the key as 'EmrgencyAttendanceId' like so.

```
[Table("reporting.EDISRecords")]
    public class EDISRecord : BaseEntity<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int EmergencyAttendanceId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Hospital { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string URNumber { get; set; }
```

**Controller action**
The controller calls the GetRecord method of the EDISRecordService passing a Lambda expression.  I use DbFunctions.TruncateTime because the database stores as date time and I only want to search on the date.

```
public ActionResult Search(string Date, string CaseNumber)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CaseNumber))
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Date);
                var EmergencyAttendance = _edisRecordService.GetRecord(m => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.ArrivalDateTime) == dt) && (m.RTAIdentifier == CaseNumber));

                    //for initialising view model
                SeperationSummaryViewModel model = new SeperationSummaryViewModel();


                //assign values for view model
                if (EmergencyAttendance != null)
                {
                    if (EmergencyAttendance.DepartureDestination != null)
                    {
                        if (EmergencyAttendance.DepartureDestination.Substring(0, 1) == ".")
                        {
                            model.DepartureDestination = EmergencyAttendance.DepartureDestination.Substring(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            model.DepartureDestination = EmergencyAttendance.DepartureDestination;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.DepartureDestination = "Not recorded by Emergency Department";
                    }
                    if (EmergencyAttendance.InpatientAdmissionDiagnosis != null)
                    {
                        model.InpatientAdmissionDiagnosis = EmergencyAttendance.InpatientAdmissionDiagnosis;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.InpatientAdmissionDiagnosis = "Not recorded by Emergency Department";
                    }
                }
                //send view model into UI (View)
                return PartialView("_SeperationInformationPartialView", model);
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Date) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CaseNumber))
                {
                    return PartialView("Blank");
                }
            }

            return PartialView("Error");
        }
```

**Service Class**
The service class instantiates a unit of work and calls the repository Get method passing through the Lambda expression.

```
public class EDISRecordService : IEDISRecordService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork<DataWarehouseDataManager> _unitOfWork;

        public EDISRecordService(IUnitOfWork<DataWarehouseDataManager> unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

       public EDISRecord GetRecord(Expression<Func<EDISRecord, bool>> @where)
        {
            return _unitOfWork.EDISRecordRepository.Get(@where);
        }



    }
```

**RepositoryBase class**
The repository class inherits from the repository base class which impliments the Get method passing the lambda to 'Expression> @where'

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : Disposable, IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dataContext;

    private IDbSet<TEntity> Dbset
    {
        get { return _dataContext.Set<TEntity>(); }
    }

    public RepositoryBase(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dbContext;
    }

    public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> @where)
    {
        return Dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (_dataContext != null)
            _dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**It fails in this method**

```
 public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> @where)
 {
     return Dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();  <<<<<< Fails Here <<<<<
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the right track and it was because I was inheriting from the Base Entity.

When I re read my problem it became clear.

The solution was to simply not to inherit from base entity class and all is good.